# access testcase name in @pytest.fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing a @pytest.fixture and I need a way to get access to the information of the name of the testcase where the fixture is used.

I just found an article that covers the topic: http://programeveryday.com/post/pytest-creating-and-using-fixtures-for-streamlined-testing/  - Thank you Dan!

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def my_fixture(request):
    print request.function.__name__
    # I like the module name, too!
    # request.module.__name__
    yield


def test_name(my_fixture):
    assert False
```

Problem is it does not work with session scope:

`E       AttributeError: function not available in session-scoped context`

Comment: As the scope describes - it's run once per whole test session and then later it's just reused for each test case. What exactly you want to do? Maybe a different approach will solve your problem.

Comment: please, I do not want to start a pytest vs sth. discussion but since you asked: placebo_session of https://github.com/garnaat/placebo assumes you use nosetests so I use a pytest fixture to do the same. It needs the module and testcase name to write the file

Comment: Oh no, I didn't meant to replace pytest (it's the best :))with something else. I just wanted to have a bigger picture so it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is no point in have a session scoped fixture, because the `@placebo_session` (from [here](https://github.com/garnaat/placebo/blob/develop/placebo/utils.py)) works per function call. So i suggest to simply do it like that:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def placebo_session(request):
    session_kwargs = {
        'region_name': os.environ.get('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1')
    }
    profile_name = os.environ.get('PLACEBO_PROFILE', None)
    if profile_name:
        session_kwargs['profile_name'] = profile_name

    session = boto3.Session(**session_kwargs)

    prefix = request.function.__name__

    base_dir = os.environ.get(
        "PLACEBO_DIR", os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "placebo"))
    record_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, prefix)

    if not os.path.exists(record_dir):
        os.makedirs(record_dir)

    pill = placebo.attach(session, data_path=record_dir)

    if os.environ.get('PLACEBO_MODE') == 'record':
        pill.record()
    else:
        pill.playback()

    return session
```

But if you will want to still have something done per session and both per testcase, you can split into two fixtures (and then use `func_session` fixture).

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def session_fixture():
  # do something one per session
  yield someobj

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def func_session(session_fixture, request):
  # do something with object created in session_fixture and
  # request.function
  yield some_val
```

Comment: that is a cool pattern. I did not think about that... thank you :)